# How do I create 2 Edge Loops adjacent to selected Edge Loop?

Tags: python, modeling, scripting, mesh, edges

I'd like to know if there are any techniques or addons available for creating adjacent edge loops in a mesh based on a selected edge loop. The functionality would be similar to the [Offset Edge Loop Tool](http://download.autodesk.com/global/docs/maya2014/en_us/index.html?url=files/Edit_Mesh__Offset_Edge_Loop_Tool.htm,topicNumber=d30e182198) in Maya.

The goal would be to find a way to do this programmatically from python, and not interactively by hand.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

'Beveling' should achieve what you want. Select the edges you want to add other edges around and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> to bevel:

[image]

Increase the 'bevel segments' by either scrolling the mouse wheel up while bevelling or change it in the toolbar (<kbd>T</kbd>) after beveling to keep the original edge.

As to how you would do this programmatically you might start with this:

```
bpy.ops.mesh.bevel(offset=0.5, segments=2, vertex_only=False)
```

(Though it might be better to try and find an alternative to `bpy.ops..`, see [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2848/why-avoid-bpy-ops))