# Batch exporting of multiple objects into separate STL files

Tags: python, export, path, osx

I have as scene with 45 objects, I am trying to write a script that will export all of the objects into separate STL files. Any ideas?

Here is a broken script I have right now:

```
import bpy
import os

# get the current path and make a new folder for the exported meshes
path = bpy.path.abspath('//1')
os.makedirs(path)

for object in bpy.context.selected_objects:

    # deselect all meshes
    bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')

    # select the object
    object.select = True

    # export object with its name as file name
    bpy.ops.export_mesh.stl(filepath=str((path + object.name + '.stl')),   use_selection=True)
```

I am getting a "Python script fail, look in the console for now..." error.
PS. I'm using a mac.

Thank you for your help!!!

Answer (score 6):

I actually found 3 issues with the original script:

- Your path creation line did not check to see if the path already existed
- Your stl export line used an incorrect parameter ("use_selection=true")
- Your path variable did not include the ending backslash so it was concatenating the stl folder name and object name

Here's my version of the working script:

```
import bpy
import os

# get the current path and make a new folder for the exported meshes
path = bpy.path.abspath('//stlexport/')

if not os.path.exists(path):
    os.makedirs(path)

for object in bpy.context.selected_objects:

    # deselect all meshes
    bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')

    # select the object
    object.select = True

    # export object with its name as file name
    fPath = str((path + object.name + '.stl'))

    #bpy.context.active_object = object
    bpy.ops.export_mesh.stl(filepath=fPath)
```

Comment: Hi Todd! Thanks for helping me out, I copied the script from somewhere else and only changed the bpy.ops.export_mesh.stl part ^^

Comment: You should also note that I altered the path variable to test the script, so you may want to change that part.

Comment: I get `AttributeError: 'Object' object has no attribute 'select'` with this script from the line `object.select = True` when I try to run it with Blender 2.93.

Answer (score 4):

It is worth noting that a script is not required for batch exporting of STL files; the *Export STL* dialogue has a *Batch Mode* setting that can be set to *Object* in order to export each part as a single STL file.  To preserve part names, leave the *File Name* field empty when exporting this way.

Regardless, the question specifically addresses a Python script.

---

There is no need to loop through selected objects.  Additional, unnecessary use of `bpy.ops` [should be avoided](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2848/why-avoid-bpy-ops).

The following script will export all of the selected objects into a specified directory (relative or absolute path):

```
import bpy
import os

# Define Directory
dir = bpy.path.abspath('//subdirectory/')

# Create Directory (If Necessary)
if not os.path.exists(dir): os.makedirs(dir)

# Export STLs
bpy.ops.export_mesh.stl(filepath = dir, batch_mode = 'OBJECT')
```

while a single line of code will suffice if the directory is known to exist (absolute path):

```
import bpy

# Export STLs
bpy.ops.export_mesh.stl(filepath = 'C:/stls/', batch_mode = 'OBJECT')
```

Note that these scripts will use the exporter's default settings ([which can be changed](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/35588/how-to-make-blender-remember-stl-export-settings-as-default?rq=1)) unless you [add arguments to the operator](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_77_0/bpy.ops.export_mesh.html#bpy.ops.export_mesh.stl).

Answer (score 1):

use_selection=True , is not a keyword argument of `export_mesh.stl`

```
- stl()
bpy.ops.export_mesh.stl(
    filepath="", 
    check_existing=True, 
    axis_forward='Y', 
    axis_up='Z', 
    filter_glob="*.stl", 
    global_scale=1, 
    use_scene_unit=False, 
    ascii=False, 
    use_mesh_modifiers=True)
```

it appears to work on the Active object, so you might use something like this:

```
import bpy
import os

# get the current path and make a new folder for the exported meshes
destination_path = '/home/zeffii/Desktop/temp_stl/'

# if path doesn't exist, create, else skip that step
if not os.path.exists(destination_path):
    os.makedirs(destination_path)

# gather names
names = [o.name for o in bpy.context.selected_objects]

# deselect all
bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')

# iterate over named objects
for name in names:

    # select the object
    obj = bpy.data.objects[name]
    bpy.context.scene.objects.active = obj

    # export object with its name as file name
    stl_path = os.path.join(destination_path, name + '.stl')
    bpy.ops.export_mesh.stl(filepath=stl_path)
```