# How to make Blender remember STL export settings as default

Tags: interface, customization, units

I model in millimeters inside Blender, for 3D printing.
Every time I want to Export STL, I have to untick **Scene Units** and change the **Scale** to `10.0`. These settings aren't remembered.

[image: Blender config for 3D printing]

How do I save them as defaults?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Solution

#### Manually

1. To remember unit settings make your adjustments then **File** > **Save Startup File** `(Ctrl-U)`
2. To change STL Export defaults navigate to
   `C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.74\scripts\addons\io_mesh_stl`
   and open the `__init__.py` file.

   `global_scale` is at [__init__.py#L166](https://git.blender.org/gitweb/gitweb.cgi/blender-addons.git/blob/HEAD:/io_mesh_stl/__init__.py#l166), change `default=1.0` to `10.0`

   `use_scene_unit` is below at [__init__.py#L172](https://git.blender.org/gitweb/gitweb.cgi/blender-addons.git/blob/HEAD:/io_mesh_stl/__init__.py#l172), change `default=True` to `False`

#### Windows PowerShell Script

[Configure Blender STL Export default settings - GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/akaleeroy/453f5ab97e1347eeede0)