# How can I compare already imported Fonts with the loaded filepath?

Tags: python, scripting, file-browser

I'm working on a part of my plugin easyText.
(http://ranincodes.wix.com/easytext)

---

I want the import Font part to automaticly check if the Font is already imported. How do I get the name of the selected file (=filebuff)?
If it is, the font should not be imported

---

This is the part of the code wich is important for it

```
#Atribute
atr = bpy.types.Scene
atr.font = StringProperty(name = "Text Font", description = "Font of the Text")
atr.filebuff = StringProperty(name = "", description = "Choose Font to Import", subtype="FILE_PATH")

#window
class windowFont (bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_space_type = "VIEW_3D"
    bl_region_type = "TOOLS"
    bl_label = "Import Font"
    bl_category = "easyText"

    def draw(self, context):
        scene = bpy.context.scene
        layout = self.layout
        layout.label("Choose + Import Font")
        col = layout.column(align = True)
        layout.prop(scene, "filebuff")
        layout.operator("load.font", text="Import", icon="LOAD_FACTORY")

#button
class OBJECT_OT_buttonLoad(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_label = "Load Font"
    bl_idname = "load.font"
    bl_description = "Import the choosen Font"

    def execute(self, context):
        scene = bpy.context.scene
        fontb = scene.filebuff
        bpy.ops.font.open(filepath=fontb, relative_path=False)
        return{'FINISHED'}
```

---

UI:[image]

---

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using the `bpy.fonts.open(...` operator you can use the `load()` command for [Font Datablocks](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_77a_release/bpy.types.BlendDataFonts.html?highlight=blenddatafonts.load#bpy.types.BlendDataFonts.load) which has a `check_existing` property built in, which should do exactly what you want:

```
bpy.data.fonts.load(filepath=fontb, check_existing=True)
```

When `check_existing` is set to `True` if a font datablock already exists in the blend file from that path then it won't be loaded, otherwise it will.

For more information on why it is generally better avoid `bpy.ops` commands read here:

[Why avoid bpy.ops?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2848/why-avoid-bpy-ops)