# Converting GUI operations to Python code?

Tags: python

If I start building my scene from scratch using GUI (read: clicking buttons), will I be able to automatically obtain the equivalent Python code that achieves the same end results?

This is a really cool feature that sounds definitely doable, but not sure how to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most actions you perform will have the operator used listed in the [info view](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/info_api_reference.html#info-view), just expand the top most editor in the default screen, you can then select and copy any of these steps and paste them into a text file that you can run like a macro.

[image: info editor]

While this is an easy way to get started and works fine for simple tasks, it is often [recommended to avoid operators](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/2848/935) in scripts, search here for [operator performance](https://blender.stackexchange.com/search?q=operator%20performance) to see discussions on the best way to do things. You will also find some steps will have better alternatives than listed in the info window, for example `bpy.ops.object.editmode_toggle()` is shown in the above list, you will find it better to use `bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')` as you clearly change to the mode you need rather than toggling from a random mode when you run the script.

As you learn using python in blender you can start making your own [operators](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/info_quickstart.html#example-operator), add them to [your own addon](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/info_tutorial_addon.html) which can be setup to bind them to shortcuts or custom menus.