# How do I subdivide a cube via scripting?

Tags: scripting, edit-mode

I have an object named "Cube" selected, and I set the mode to EDIT via

```
cube = bpy.data.objects.get('Cube')
cube.select=True
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')
```

I want to subdivide each edge into 3 parts. In the editor, I can click Tools -> Subdivide, and then adjust the number of cuts below in a menu.

I cannot find any methods of the bmesh object class to do this, though.

Answer (score 2):

**Using [`BMesh.subdivide_edges(...)`](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bmesh.ops.html#bmesh.ops.subdivide_edges)**

---

Can use [`BMesh.subdivide_edges(...)`](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bmesh.ops.html#bmesh.ops.subdivide_edges) with 3 cuts, and grid fill set to true.

```
import bpy
import bmesh
context = bpy.context
obj = context.edit_object
me = obj.data
bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(me)
bmesh.ops.subdivide_edges(bm,
        edges=bm.edges,
        use_grid_fill=True,
        cuts=3)
me.update()
```

There is an example in [my answer here demonstrating](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/102239/15543) how to use `bmesh.ops.subdivide` with a different number of cuts on each dimension.

Answer (score 1):

I am getting used to the way the Python manual is written, and I realized the way you do this is simply

```
bpy.ops.mesh.subdivide(number_cuts=3)
```

As long as the cube is select and edit mode is active.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2848/why-avoid-bpy-ops

Comment: Is there a better way to perform the subdivision without using bpy.ops?

Comment: Well, there will probably be a way using the `bmesh` module.