# Bmesh bevel is inverted

Tags: python, bmesh

This looks cool and all, but it's beveled in the wrong direction. How can I flip the direction it bevels, so it looks more like a rounded cube, rather than a rounded plus-sign?

```
import bpy
import bmesh

from bpy.props import (
        BoolProperty,
        BoolVectorProperty,
        FloatProperty,
        FloatVectorProperty,
        IntProperty,
        )

#Returns all edges parallel to x-axis:
def get_x_parallel_edges(bm):
    #The returned list of edges:
    e_list = []

    #Look for all the edges that
    #run parallel to the x-axis:
    for f in bm.faces:
        for e in f.edges:
            #Rename the coords:
            ey0 = e.verts[0].co.y
            ey1 = e.verts[1].co.y
            ez0 = e.verts[0].co.z
            ez1 = e.verts[1].co.z
            #Check them:
            if ey0 == ey1 and ez0 == ez1:
                #Check for duplicates:
                is_duplicate = False
                for el in e_list:
                    if el == e:
                        is_duplicate = True
                if not is_duplicate:
                    e_list += [e]

    return e_list

#Break a list of edges
#into a list of verts:
def get_v_from_e(edges):
    #The returned list of verts:
    v_list = []

    #Break apart the edges into verts:
    for e in edges:
        for v in e.verts:
            #Check for duplicates:
            is_duplicate = False
            for vl in v_list:
                if vl == v:
                    is_duplicate = True
            if not is_duplicate:
                v_list += [v]
    return v_list

class AddBevCube(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "mesh.primitive_bev_cube_add"
    bl_label = "Add Beveled Cube"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}

    length = FloatProperty(
            name="Length",
            description="Box Length",
            min=0.01, max=100.0,
            default=4.0,
            )
    width = FloatProperty(
            name="Width",
            description="Box Width",
            min=0.01, max=100.0,
            default=3.0,
            )
    height = FloatProperty(
            name="Height",
            description="Box Height",
            min=0.01, max=100.0,
            default=2.0,
            )
    bev_seg = IntProperty(
            name="Segments",
            description="Bevel Segments",
            min=1, max=100,
            default=3,
            )
    bev_offset = FloatProperty(
            name="Offset",
            description="Bevel Offset",
            min=0.01, max=100.0,
            default=0.125,
            )

    def execute(self, context):

        #Rename the variables:
        l = self.length
        w = self.width
        h = self.height
        seg = self.bev_seg
        b_offset = self.bev_offset

        #Make the cube object stuff:
        mesh = bpy.data.meshes.new("cube")
        cube_obj = bpy.data.objects.new("Cube_Obj", mesh)

        scene = bpy.context.scene
        scene.objects.link(cube_obj)
        bm = bmesh.new()

        #Add the cube:
        bmesh.ops.create_cube(bm, size=0.5)
        #Apply size:
        bmesh.ops.scale(bm, vec=(l, w, h))

        #First, get the verts and edges:
        e_geom = get_x_parallel_edges(bm)
        v_geom = get_v_from_e(e_geom)
        #Now bevel:
        bmesh.ops.bevel(bm, 
                        geom=v_geom[:] + e_geom[:], 
                        offset=b_offset, 
                        offset_type=0, 
                        segments=seg,
                        clamp_overlap=True)

        bm.to_mesh(mesh)
        mesh.update()

        return {'FINISHED'}


def menu_func(self, context):
    self.layout.operator(AddBevCube.bl_idname, icon='MESH_CUBE')


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(AddBevCube)
    bpy.types.INFO_MT_mesh_add.append(menu_func)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(AddBevCube)
    bpy.types.INFO_MT_mesh_add.remove(menu_func)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Set the profile**

[image]

basically your issue was using the default value of `0.0` for the `profile` property of the bevel operator. I have set it to `0.5` below. Might be a contender for another operator property.

Test code including, what I believe are simpler, routines for finding parallel edges and the vertices they contain. *also added some notes re upgrading to 2.8*

```
import bpy
import bmesh
from mathutils import Vector

from bpy.props import (
        BoolProperty,
        BoolVectorProperty,
        FloatProperty,
        FloatVectorProperty,
        IntProperty,
        )

#Test if edge e parallel to vector v:
def parallel(e, v, eps=1e-6):
    # normalized edge direction vector
    d = (e.verts[1].co - e.verts[0].co).normalized()
    return abs(v.normalized().dot(d)) >= 1 - eps


class MESH_OT_primitive_bev_cube_add(bpy.types.Operator):
    '''Add Beveled Cube'''
    bl_idname = "mesh.primitive_bev_cube_add"
    bl_label = "Add Beveled Cube"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}

    length = FloatProperty(
            name="Length",
            description="Box Length",
            min=0.01, max=100.0,
            default=4.0,
            )
    width = FloatProperty(
            name="Width",
            description="Box Width",
            min=0.01, max=100.0,
            default=3.0,
            )
    height = FloatProperty(
            name="Height",
            description="Box Height",
            min=0.01, max=100.0,
            default=2.0,
            )
    bev_seg = IntProperty(
            name="Segments",
            description="Bevel Segments",
            min=1, max=100,
            default=3,
            )
    bev_offset = FloatProperty(
            name="Offset",
            description="Bevel Offset",
            min=0.01, max=100.0,
            default=0.125,
            )

    def execute(self, context):

        #Make the cube object stuff:
        mesh = bpy.data.meshes.new("cube")
        cube_obj = bpy.data.objects.new("Cube_Obj", mesh)

        scene = context.scene
        scene.objects.link(cube_obj)
        #scene.collection.objects.link(cube_obj)
        bm = bmesh.new()

        #Add the cube:
        bmesh.ops.create_cube(bm, size=0.5)
        #Apply size:
        bmesh.ops.scale(bm, 
                verts=bm.verts,
                vec=(self.length, self.width, self.height))

        #First, get the verts and edges:
        x_axis = Vector((1, 0, 0))
        e_geom = [e for e in bm.edges if parallel(e, x_axis)]
        v_geom = set(v for e in e_geom for v in e.verts)
        #Now bevel:
        bmesh.ops.bevel(bm, 
                        geom=list(v_geom) + e_geom[:], 
                        offset=self.bev_offset, 
                        offset_type=0,
                        # offset_type='OFFSET', 
                        profile=0.5,
                        segments=self.bev_seg,
                        clamp_overlap=True)

        bm.to_mesh(mesh)
        mesh.update()

        return {'FINISHED'}


def menu_func(self, context):
    self.layout.operator(MESH_OT_primitive_bev_cube_add.bl_idname, icon='MESH_CUBE')


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(MESH_OT_primitive_bev_cube_add)
    bpy.types.INFO_MT_mesh_add.append(menu_func)
    #bpy.types.VIEw3D_MT_mesh_add.append(menu_func)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(MESH_OT_primitive_bev_cube_add)
    bpy.types.INFO_MT_mesh_add.remove(menu_func)
    #bpy.types.VIEw3D_MT_mesh_add.remove(menu_func)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Please note it is standard practice to set the newly created object to active and selected, as well as selecting the new geometry created.

2.7x https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/102239/15543

2.8 https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/133880/15543

Comment: My issue was that I thought the profile defaulted to 0.5! I was trying to set it to -0.5 at one point, too (which I realize would have clamped it to 0). Thank you!