# How to link the adjust last operation menu to object? Blender 2.80 - 2.81

Tags: python

What am I missing or doing wrong?
I made this script to add a cylinder ( just to learn ) but the adjust last operation menu does not work all.
What do i need to do to get this linked to the cylinder?
In the end I want to add some functions same as current add cylinder but also other funtions.

I guess there is no link between the bl-idname and the cylinder

This is my code

```
    bl_info = {
    "name": "New Object",
    "author": "Your Name Here",
    "version": (1, 0),
    "blender": (2, 80, 1),
    "location": "View3D > Add > Mesh > New Object",
    "description": "Adds a new Mesh Object",
    "warning": "",
    "wiki_url": "",
    "category": "Add Mesh",
}


import bpy
from bpy.types import Operator
from bpy.props import FloatVectorProperty
from bpy_extras.object_utils import AddObjectHelper, object_data_add
from mathutils import Vector

radius = 1
depth = 2
location = (0, 0, 0)
rotation = (0, 0, 0)

class OBJECT_OT_add_object(Operator, AddObjectHelper):
    """Create a new Mesh Object"""
    bl_idname = "cylinder.add_object"
    bl_label = "Add Mesh Object"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}

    def execute(self, context):

        bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cylinder_add(radius=radius, depth=depth, location=location, rotation=rotation)

        return {'FINISHED'}


# Registration
def add_object_button(self, context):
    self.layout.operator(
        OBJECT_OT_add_object.bl_idname,
        text="Add Object123",
        icon='PLUGIN')


# This allows you to right click on a button and link to documentation
def add_object_manual_map():
    url_manual_prefix = "https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/"
    url_manual_mapping = (
        ("bpy.ops.mesh.add_object", "scene_layout/object/types.html"),
    )
    return url_manual_prefix, url_manual_mapping


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(OBJECT_OT_add_object)
    bpy.utils.register_manual_map(add_object_manual_map)
    bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_mesh_add.append(add_object_button)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(OBJECT_OT_add_object)
    bpy.utils.unregister_manual_map(add_object_manual_map)
    bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_mesh_add.remove(add_object_button)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Answer (score 5):

That's pretty close. Just add *real properties* to the operator class. Minimal example:

[image]

```
import bpy
from bpy.types import Operator
from bpy.props import IntProperty, FloatProperty, FloatVectorProperty


class OBJECT_OT_add_object(Operator):
    """Create a new Mesh Object"""
    bl_idname = "your_category.add_object"
    bl_label = "Add Mesh Object"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}

    my_radius : FloatProperty()
    my_depth : IntProperty()
    my_location : FloatVectorProperty()
    my_rotation : FloatVectorProperty()

    def execute(self, context):
        # Call primitve_add
        bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cylinder_add(
            radius = self.my_radius, 
            depth = self.my_depth, 
            location = self.my_location, 
            rotation = self.my_rotation)

        return {'FINISHED'}


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(OBJECT_OT_add_object)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(OBJECT_OT_add_object)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Further reading: https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.props.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer This was what i was looking for. May i ask you where i can find documentation about FloatVectorProperty? For example what kind of property is align?

Comment: Added the link to the API, there you have a list of all available properties. Properties are basically data types (int, float, string etc) so in case of "align" it depends what do you want to do (Yes/Nope? -> Bool). Also I'd suggest read [How to create a custom UI?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57306/how-to-create-a-custom-ui/57332#57332) @DGRL

Comment: Maybe keep  the `AddObjectHelper` subclass to deal with the usual suspects loc, rot, scale, align.

Answer (score 2):

**With the `AddObjectHelper` class**

[image]

Further to @brockmann's answer

The `AddObjectHelper` class sets up some of the usual suspects for us, including location, rotation and align.   It appears you have used the *`text editor > templates > python > Addon add object`* template, so let's stick with it in.

If we simply ourselves add

```
rotation : FloatVectorProperty()
```

the rotation will always show in the base unit of radians.  360 degrees = 2pi radians.  In scene unit settings degrees is the default set to **display** in the UI

```
rotation : FloatVectorProperty(unit='ROTATION')
```

is required in the property definition to make it behave like other rotation props.  Just as `unit='LENGTH'` will add metres etc.

All this is done for us by the helper class..

```
class OBJECT_OT_add_cylinder(Operator, AddObjectHelper):
    """Create a new Mesh Object"""
    bl_idname = "object.add_cylinder"
    bl_label = "Add Mesh Object"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}

    # set other args like name and description for all
    vertices : IntProperty(
            name="Vertices",
            description="Number of Vertices",
            min=0,
            default=32)
    radius : IntProperty(default=2)
    depth : FloatProperty(default=2)

    def execute(self, context):

        bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cylinder_add(
                vertices=self.vertices,
                radius=self.radius, 
                depth=self.depth, 
                # those defined in AddObjectHelper
                align=self.align, 
                location=self.location, 
                rotation=self.rotation)

        return {'FINISHED'}
```

*Note: I've adjusted the classname `OBJECT_OT_add_cylinder`and `bl_idname = "object.add_cylinder"` to match desired naming convention*

One issue tho is that its draw method puts its stuff first, so may need to add your own draw method to re-sort as desired

```
    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        layout.prop(self, "vertices")
        layout.prop(self, "radius")
        # and so on
```

Other examples based on add object template

https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/133880/15543

https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/102239/15543