# TypeError: MESH_OT_add_triangle.is_property_set("location") not found

Tags: mesh, scripting, bmesh

I get this error when I add a mesh object to my scene, but I don't know what it means:

```
Error: Python: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\triangle-test\ui-triangle.py", line 36, in execute
    object_data_add(context, steeve.mesh, operator=self)
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.91\2.91\scripts\modules\bpy_extras\object_utils.py", line 130, in object_data_add
    obj_new.matrix_world = add_object_align_init(context, operator)
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.91\2.91\scripts\modules\bpy_extras\object_utils.py", line 60, in add_object_align_init
    if operator and properties.is_property_set("location"):
TypeError: MESH_OT_add_triangle.is_property_set("location") not found
```

The object is effectively added to the scene but usually I notice that Blender crashes after a few seconds.

Note: I have an operator named T2T_TRIANGLE_add_triangle but no MESH_OT_add_triangle, I suppose it's generated internally.

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**

Code of the operator:

```
class T2T_TRIANGLE_add_triangle(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Create a new triangle object"""
    bl_idname = "mesh.add_triangle"
    bl_label = "Add Triangle"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}

    lvl = bpy.props.IntProperty(name="Level:", default=2, set=set_level)
    ang = bpy.props.FloatProperty(name="Angle:", default=60, set=set_angle)

    level = 2
    angle = 60

    def execute(self, context):
        steeve = Triangle(level=self.level, angle=self.angle)
        object_data_add(context, steeve.mesh, operator=self)
        steeve.mesh.validate(verbose=True)
        return {'FINISHED'}

    def invoke(self, context, event):
        return context.window_manager.invoke_props_dialog(self)

def set_level(self, value):
    self["level"] = value


def set_angle(self, value):
    self["angle"] = value
```

Comment: Recommend if you have code that produces errors, post the code not the error (or both).  You have defined an operator class named `T2T_TRIANGLE_add_triangle`  and given it the class property `bl_idname = "mesh.add_triangle"`.  Blender uses the idname to create the registerred class name  `MESH_OT_add_triangle`  (where OT is Operator Type)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The operator requires a `location, rotation, align` property.**

If you are going to use `object_data_add` to add an object to the scene then make sure you use mixin class `AddObjectHelper`  *As demonstrated in the addon add object template*

```
from bpy_extras.object_utils import AddObjectHelper, object_data_add

class OBJECT_OT_add_object(Operator, AddObjectHelper):
    """Create a new Mesh Object"""
    bl_idname = "mesh.add_object"
    bl_label = "Add Mesh Object"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}

    scale: FloatVectorProperty(
        name="scale",
        default=(1.0, 1.0, 1.0),
        subtype='TRANSLATION',
        description="scaling",
    )

    def execute(self, context):

        add_object(self, context)

        return {'FINISHED'
```

or annotate your class with the usual suspects `location, rotation, align`  See https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/160995/15543