# Are bpy_extras.object_utils.object_data_add created mesh objects relative to the global origin or cursor location?

Tags: python, mesh, add-on

I trying to dynamically create meshes using the python API and it seems that coordinates are relative to the cursor location instead of the global zero point?

Is this correct? And if so, is there a way to make blender do it relative to (0, 0, 0)

Code:

```
_mesh1 = bpy.data.meshes.new(name='testing_mesh1')

vertices1 = [Vector((a, b, c)) ...]
edges1 = [(0, 1) ...]

_mesh1.from_pydata(vertices1, edges1, [])

bpy_extras.object_utils.object_data_add(context, _mesh1)
```

Comment: Please add code to clarify how you are adding objects. If using operators, yes the default setting is to add at scene.cursor location.  If `location` argument is set it is relative to global origin.

Comment: I have added the code that I use

Answer (score 2):

**Simple test in python console**

Run a simple test. Put the cursor at some known scene location, and add an object using the `bpy_extras.object_utils.object_data_add` method. (*Simply pinched a mesh from the active object cube*)

```
>>> C.object
bpy.data.objects['Cube']

>>> me = C.object.data
>>> C.scene.cursor.location = (10, 10, 10)
>>> import bpy_extras
>>> ob = bpy_extras.object_utils.object_data_add(C, me)

>>> ob.location
Vector((10.0, 10.0, 10.0))
```

Hence without any operator passed, uses the scene cursor. *btw the python source is readily available, and could check thru *`scripts/modules/bpy_extras/object_utils.py`* to confirm*

To make it zero location, rotation and unit scale

```
>>> ob.matrix_world = Matrix()
>>> ob.location
Vector((0.0, 0.0, 0.0))
```

**Check the docstring**

For a quick run down check the docstring in the python console

```
>>> bpy_extras.object_utils.object_data_add(
object_data_add(context, obdata, operator=None, name=None)
Add an object using the view context and preference to initialize the
location, rotation and layer.
:arg context: The context to use.
:type context: :class:`bpy.types.Context`
:arg obdata: the data used for the new object.
:type obdata: valid object data type or None.
:arg operator: The operator, checked for location and rotation properties.
:type operator: :class:`bpy.types.Operator`
:arg name: Optional name
:type name: string
:return: the newly created object in the scene.
:rtype: :class:`bpy.types.Object`
```

**Use in conjunction with an operator**

is designed to be used in conjunction with an add object operator in which case transform settings are taken from the instance of the operator.  Often also used with `AddObjectHelper` class, as demonstrated in *`Text Editor > Python > Templates > Add Object`*  and in this example https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/160995

**Using a decorator**

An example of wrapping a decorator around the imported method to set the new object created to a transform of our choosing.

```
import bpy
from bpy_extras.object_utils import object_data_add
from mathutils import Matrix

def location_decorator(matrix=Matrix()):
    def decorator(f):
        def g(*args, **kwargs):
            ob = f(*args, **kwargs)
            ob.matrix_world = matrix
            return ob
        return g 
    return decorator

object_data_add = location_decorator()(object_data_add)

me = bpy.data.meshes.new("Foo")

ob = object_data_add(bpy.context, me)
```

or if using with an operator that has a location property, but we wish to make it default to scene origin (or another transform) when not set then

```
def location_decorator(matrix=Matrix()):
    def decorator(f):
        def g(*args, **kwargs):
            op = kwargs.get("operator")

            if op and not op.properties.is_property_set("location"):                    
                op.location = matrix.translation
            return f(*args, **kwargs)
        return g 
    return decorator
```