# Gridifying Objects using BMesh

Tags: python, mesh, scripting, bmesh

I'm working on a script which generates a bunch of cuboids with integer length sides. From there I would like to effectively turn each face into a grid in which each vertex is aligned to the world grid (i.e. on each integer coordinate). Currently I have been looking at using the subdivide operation (`bmesh.ops.subdivide_edges`) to make this work, but this seems long-winded and time-consuming (requires getting all the edges from each operation, finding out which to use for the next, etc). Is there a better way of doing this, or would it be easier to do repeated extrusion when constructing the cuboid (i.e. extrude by 1, n times, rather than extrude by n once)? The way I would do this manually is using a loop cut, can this be done with bmesh?

For info, I'm using blender 2.81a and hoping to do this purely within bmesh.

[image: Current result] [image: Intended result]

Thanks in advance,
Jacob

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/102239/15543  Ultimately yes would create an AxB grid and extrude C.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into implementing something similar

Comment: Thanks for directing me to that post! Implemented the same method, worked perfectly, cheers.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Subdividing cubes at different intervals](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/102207/subdividing-cubes-at-different-intervals)

Answer (score 0):

To anyone else looking to implement this, please see the link batFINGER directed me to: [link](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/102239/15543)