# How to select with python code only vertical edges from cube?

Tags: python, scripting

How to select the vertical edges, using python code if a selected previously the cube?

[image: Vertical edges]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this script to select each edge if its two vertices' X and Y coordinate are both really close to each other.

```
import bpy
import bmesh

obj = bpy.context.active_object  # Get selected object

epsilon = 1e-5  # Threshold to account for floating point precision

if obj:
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')  # Go into edit mode
    bpy.ops.mesh.select_mode(type="EDGE")  # Switch to edge select mode

    bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(obj.data)  # Create bmesh object for easy mesh evaluation

    for e in bm.edges:  # Check all edges
        first_pos = e.verts[0].co  # Get first vert position of this edge
        other_pos = e.verts[1].co  # Get second vert position of this edge

        # Select or deselect depending of the relative position of both vertices
        e.select_set(abs(first_pos.x - other_pos.x) <= epsilon and abs(first_pos.y - other_pos.y) <= epsilon)
        
    bmesh.update_edit_mesh(obj.data)  # Update the mesh in edit mode
```

[image]

[How to run a script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11604548/7092409)

Comment: how you recorded the video?

Comment: I used the software ScreenToGif

Answer (score 2):

**The dot product**

If two vectors are parallel then the dot product of their normalized direction will be 1 if in same direction (angle between 0) or -1 in opposite direction -1 (angle between 180 degrees)

Checking that the absolute value of dot product is around 1 will find edges defined by the vertex coordinate difference regardless of order.

Have used this method in example here [Subdividing cubes at different intervals](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/102207/subdividing-cubes-at-different-intervals/102239#102239)

So similarly

```
    def aligned(e, axis, TOL=1e-5):
        axis = Vector(axis).normalized()
        dir = (e.verts[1].co - e.verts[0].co).normalized()
        return (1 - abs(dir.dot(axis))) < TOL

    # select if aligned with local z axis.
    for e in bm.edges:
        e.select_set(aligned(e, (0, 0, 1)) 

    # select if aligned with global z axis
    axis = ob.matrix_world.inverted() @ Vector((0, 0, 1)) # local space
    for e in bm.edges:
        e.select_set(aligned(e, axis))
```

(if doubles in mesh will need to deal with zero length edges.)

**Hardcode for default cube.**

if this is a freshly added  default cube can rely on the edges having the same index each time, and could select based on index.

```
geom=[e.index for e in bm.edges if aligned(e, (0, 0, 1))]
print(geom)
```

Outputs `[1, 3, 6, 9]`
so the  bmesh edges of the default cube in $Z$ dir are

```
bm.edges.ensure_lookup_table()
vertical_edges = [bm.edges[i] for i in (1, 3, 6, 9)]
```

Comment: How rather than selecing every edge in the shape how can you select just one edge any edge?