# Block with rounded edges in python

Tags: python, mesh, scripting

I can easily make a primitive box with python code. But I would like to make the edges parallel to the z-axis rounded with a given radius. Sort of like the picture below but without all the subdivision. (that was just me being bad at Blender). Does anyone know a way to script such an object with specified height, width depth and corner radius?

[image]

EDIT: I found this link, but it is not easily translated to python.

https://www.loekvandenouweland.com/content/round-corners-only-on-x-y-plane-in-blender.html

Comment: i think you know how to create the cube and how to use the bevel. modifier -> you see the commands in the console. All you need is the selection of the edges in python, so combine this with that answer here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/182182/how-to-select-with-python-code-only-vertical-edges-from-cube

Comment: An easy way might be to create a plane, collect all the vertices and bevel them, then collect all the vertices again and extrude.

Comment: @batFINGER i feel really honored that master batFINGER concurs me ;) –

Answer (score 2):

**BMesh script.**

[image]
*"Spam tin" created with script below, in edit mode. Note has ngon top and bottom.*

The bmesh equivalent of example linked in question using `bpy.ops.mesh.bevel(...)`

[image]

which is pretty much the `bmesh.ops.bevel` equivalent.

Select the four vertical edges [How to select with python code only vertical edges from cube?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/182182/how-to-select-with-python-code-only-vertical-edges-from-cube) and pass into operator.

Test script, run in OBJECT mode.

```
import bpy
import bmesh
from mathutils import Vector
context = bpy.context

corner_radius = 0.2 # 0.5 > cylinder 
corner_segments = 5
width, depth, height = (1.5, 1, 2)

bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add()
ob = context.object
me = ob.data
bm = bmesh.new()
bm.from_mesh(me)

bm.edges.ensure_lookup_table()
# scale first to keep corners round
bmesh.ops.scale(
        bm,
        verts=bm.verts,
        vec=(width, depth, height),
        )  
bmesh.ops.bevel(
        bm,
        geom=[bm.edges[i] for i in (1, 3, 6, 9)],
        loop_slide=True,
        affect='EDGES',
        profile=0.5, # round
        offset=corner_radius * 2,
        segments=corner_segments,
        )
      
bm.to_mesh(me)
```