# Loop through planes and do a center loop cut script

Tags: scripting, loop

I am trying to write a simple script which should loop through the selected objects (all simple square planes) and do a loop cut operation in order to split the plane in half.

EDIT: What I have runs, but now only cuts the active object:

EDITED IN A SIMPLER VERSION:

```
import bpy

bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'OBJECT')

# If there ARE objects selected then act on all objects
if bpy.context.selected_objects != []:
    for obj in bpy.context.selected_objects:
        if obj.type == 'MESH': 
            print("&gt;&gt;&gt;&gt;", obj.name)
            bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'EDIT') 

            obj = bpy.context.active_object

            def view3d_find( return_area = False ):
                # returns first 3d view, normally we get from context
                for area in bpy.context.window.screen.areas:
                    if area.type == 'VIEW_3D':
                        v3d = area.spaces[0]
                        rv3d = v3d.region_3d
                        for region in area.regions:
                            if region.type == 'WINDOW':
                                if return_area: return region, rv3d, v3d, area
                                return region, rv3d, v3d
                return None, None

            region, rv3d, v3d, area = view3d_find(True)

            override = {
                'scene'  : bpy.context.scene,
                'region' : region,
                'area'   : area,
                'space'  : v3d
            }

            bpy.ops.mesh.loopcut_slide(
                override, 
                MESH_OT_loopcut = {
                    "number_cuts"           : 1,
                    "smoothness"            : 0,     
                    "falloff"               : 'SMOOTH',  # Was 'INVERSE_SQUARE' that does not exist
                    "edge_index"            : 1,
                    "object_index"          : 0,
                    "mesh_select_mode_init" : (True, False, False)
                }
            )
```

Seems the problem stems from the active object being the only thing taking the loop cuts. Help on where I've gone wrong would be great! Thanks!

Comment: All selected objects will be put into edit mode. Can set the active object with `context.view_layer.objects.active = obj`  or  add teh object to the overrirde, since all are in edit mode. Somewhat related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/102207/subdividing-cubes-at-different-intervals/102239?r=SearchResults&s=1|29.7080#102239

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how to implement this code snippet, nothing changes when adding that in the loop body.

Comment: `bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = obj` is what I needed! Note the prefix bpy.* is the only thing missing. Can you add an answer batFINGER