# Incorrect context Runtime Error on calling .poll() method via command line

Tags: python, scripting, audio

I'm trying to get a python based audio visualisation script to work in blender via command line interface. Here's the code [myscript.py](https://gist.github.com/tjb0607/1357185/5e3b3bcad859840616123d3565de9ca698edd299)

When I run the following in blender 2.66 on Ubuntu 14.04

`blender -b -noaudio -P myscript.py`

I get the following error

```
File "/home/random9/myscript.py", line 66, in <module>
bpy.ops.anim.keyframe_insert_menu(type='Scaling')
File "/usr/share/blender/2.79/scripts/modules/bpy/ops.py", line 189, in __call__
ret = op_call(self.idname_py(), None, kw)

RuntimeError: Operator bpy.ops.anim.keyframe_insert_menu.poll() failed,
context is incorrect
```

in [line number 66]

`bpy.ops.anim.keyframe_insert_menu(type='Scaling')`

How do I resolve this error?

I've been going through [the python scripting docs](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_69_release/info_gotcha.html#why-does-an-operator-s-poll-fail) and it suggests that I should be able to figure out what context an operator needs simply by seeing how it’s used in Blender and thinking about what it does.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You can avoid the keyframe insert menu operator  completely with `context.object.keyframe_insert("scale", group="Scale")`

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2848/why-avoid-bpy-ops

Comment: @batFINGER, however armature data objects have no keyframe_insert_menu method.

Comment: You can avoid the keyframe insert menu **operator** completely with `context.object.keyframe_insert("scale", group="Scale")`

Comment: @batFINGER, thx. With your suggestion, I substitute `bpy.ops.anim.keyframe_insert_menu(type='BUILTIN_KSI_VisualLocRotScale')` with ```obj.keyframe_insert('location', group='Location');
obj.keyframe_insert('scale', group='Scale');
obj.keyframe_insert('rotation_quaternion', group='Rotation')```, and everything works fine!