# link nodes in compositor blender 2.8

Tags: python, scripting, node-editor

While trying to link two nodes via python I get this error:

```
AttributeError: 'set' object has no attribute 'output'
```

I can't understand why, following the docs seems to be correct the code, which is:

```
def compile_met(image_selected):

        # switch on nodes and get reference
        bpy.context.scene.use_nodes = True
        tree = bpy.context.scene.node_tree

        prev = bpy.context.area.type
        bpy.context.area.type = 'NODE_EDITOR'

        area = bpy.context.area    

        # clear default nodes
        for node in tree.nodes:
                tree.nodes.remove(node)

        # create input image node
        image_node = bpy.ops.node.add_file( filepath=image_selected)
        comp_node = bpy.ops.node.add_and_link_node(type="CompositorNodeComposite")

        # link nodes
        links = tree.links
        link = links.new(image_node.output['Image'], comp_node.input[1])

        bpy.context.area.type = prev
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two issues here.

The first is that `bpy.ops.node.add_file` does not return the new node, it simply returns a [`set`](https://docs.blender.org/api/2.79/bpy.types.Operator.html#bpy.types.Operator.execute) containing a message of the status of the current operator. E.g. it will return `{'FINISHED'}` if it is successful.

`bpy.ops` functions are operators, which expect to be run from particular parts of the interface, not from code, hence why you are currently having to change the `area.type` to `NODE_EDITOR` before the code will work and why they're not returning the data they create. (You can read more [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2848/why-avoid-bpy-ops) why `bpy.ops` should be avoided when possible.)

Instead, you can access the node data more directly (if a little more manually):

```
image = bpy.data.images.load(filepath="Your filepath")
image_node = bpy.context.scene.node_tree.nodes.new('CompositorNodeImage')
image_node.image = image
```

And then the same for `comp_node`:

```
comp_node = bpy.context.scene.node_tree.nodes.new('CompositorNodeComposite')
```

These functions *do* return the new nodes and by manually loading the image, instead of relying on an operator, *and* manually adding the image node and composite node you can a) return the new image and nodes to variables, b) use the returned data to link the image to the node and c) not have to set `area.type` any more because you're not using `bpy.ops`.

This will fix the first problem, but not the second. The second is that the nodes do not have an `output` or `input` property, they're plurals so they're called `outputs` and `inputs`, e.g.:

```
links.new(image_node.outputs['Image'], comp_node.inputs[1])
```