# Ungrouping a node group with Python

Tags: python, scripting

What is the correct way to ungroup a node group from a script?

Essentially, I have a material that contains both nodes and node groups. I would like to expand all node groups in that material, leaving just "regular" nodes.

I have tried to "cheat" by making the node group selected and active, and then trying to call bpy.ops.node.group_ungroup(). This, however, gives an error that the context is not correct, and I don't know how to correct it.

I don't want to use bpy.ops if it can be avoided. My objective is simply to ungroup all nodes in a given material. I believe that I must be able to do this through bpy.data, I just don't know how.

Comment: One way you can correct it, is to save the current context, change the context to whatever context is needed to ungroup it, ungroup and change the context back to what it was

Comment: @WhatAMesh Without meaning to sound too helpless... I have no idea how to do any of that. I don't even know how to work out what context it needs, let alone how to change the context. Nothing like that has come up in any Blender coding I have done so far.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [poll() failed, context incorrect? - Example: bpy.ops.view3d.background\_image\_add()](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6101/poll-failed-context-incorrect-example-bpy-ops-view3d-background-image-add)

Comment: @brockmann Not even close to a duplicate of that. If anything, my original question was about how to avoid using bpy.ops.

Comment: There is no way I can think of besides coping the nodes to the root level so I think the way to go *is* using `group_ungroup()`. BTW: I don't get why people always want to *avoid* bpy.ops*.

Comment: @brockmann https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2848/why-avoid-bpy-ops

Answer (score 2):

I can't find any low-level way to *un-group* the nodes. Consider that `ops.node.group_ungroup()` does a lot of things for free (keeps the references/data of the nodes, removes the input and output node, keeps the connections etc.) so I'd suggest to write your own operator and just call it within the *Node Editor* either by using <kbd>spacebar</kbd> or creating a button.

```
import bpy

def main(operator, context):
    space = context.space_data
    node_tree = space.node_tree
    node_active = context.active_node
    node_selected = context.selected_nodes

    if node_active.type == 'GROUP':
        bpy.ops.node.group_ungroup()

class NodeOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Tooltip"""
    bl_idname = "node.simple_operator"
    bl_label = "Simple Node Operator"

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        space = context.space_data
        return space.type == 'NODE_EDITOR'

    def execute(self, context):
        main(self, context)
        return {'FINISHED'}


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(NodeOperator)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(NodeOperator)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

In case there is no way around calling `bpy.ops.node.group_ungroup()` within the *Node Editor*, you can switch the current area. 
Example based on: [poll() failed, context incorrect? - Example: bpy.ops.view3d.background_image_add()](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6101/poll-failed-context-incorrect-example-bpy-ops-view3d-background-image-add)

```
import bpy

def main(operator, context):

    area = context.area
    old_type = area.type

    # Set the area to NODE_EDITOR
    area.type = 'NODE_EDITOR'

    space = context.space_data
    node_tree = space.node_tree
    node_active = context.active_node
    node_selected = context.selected_nodes

    if node_active.type == 'GROUP':
        bpy.ops.node.group_ungroup()

    # Reset properties area
    area.type = old_type


class NodeOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Tooltip"""
    bl_idname = "node.simple_operator"
    bl_label = "Simple Node Operator"
    '''
    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        space = context.space_data
        return space.type == 'NODE_EDITOR'
    '''
    def execute(self, context):
        main(self, context)
        return {'FINISHED'}


class LayoutDemoPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    """Creates a Panel in the scene context of the properties editor"""
    bl_label = "Layout Demo"
    bl_idname = "SCENE_PT_layout"
    bl_space_type = 'PROPERTIES'
    bl_region_type = 'WINDOW'
    bl_context = "scene"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout

        scene = context.scene
        layout.operator(NodeOperator.bl_idname)


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(NodeOperator)
    bpy.utils.register_class(LayoutDemoPanel)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(NodeOperator)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(LayoutDemoPanel)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Comment: I need to do the un-grouping inside my existing operator. My operator is called from a button on the panel. I think I need to override the context somehow?

Comment: On which pane? In case the panel is part of the *Node Editor*, there is nothing to switch or override or anything @Lewis

Comment: The panel is located in the render context of the properties panel. bl_space_type = "PROPERTIES" bl_region_type= "WINDOW" bl_context = "render" @brockmann

Comment: Question is whether that's really necessary. Why you can't just place a second one into the *Properties Panel* of the node editor? Switching the editor from e.g. *3d View* to *Node Editor* is error-prone as hell so I wouldn't recommend that @Lewis

Comment: No, that wouldn't work at all. It's part of one big operation. Fiddling with the nodes is just one part of it, and it all has to happen when the user clicks the button. I already manipulate the node tree (mostly adding nodes) with no issue. It's just the ability to unpack a node group that's caused me an issue as I can't find any python function to do that. I don't really want to resort to bpy.ops if I can avoid it. @brockmann

Comment: Yep. Unfortunately blender isn't really designed for such cases. However, it's possible to do but it will be a pain to debug @Lewis

Comment: It's not a matter of Blender's "design"... you can do almost anything with scripting. There will be a way of doing it without resorting to bpy.ops. I just don't know how to do it correctly (hence the question). Hopefully someone will.

Comment: It literally is, go through the API and you'll see that there is no low-level way of doing that in an easy and especially safe way @Lewis

Comment: You are saying that I can add nodes, delete nodes, change node properties, link nodes, unlink nodes, move nodes, rename nodes (all of which my script already does - easily and safely) - but for some reason the "design" of Blender draws the line at un-grouping a node group.....? Sorry - doesn't ring true to me.

Comment: Read the post I've linked, it's not about *nodes*, it's about *context*. Operators always have a *context* from which they can be called @Lewis

Comment: Read my comments. My primary question is how to do this with bpy.data and not bpy.ops. I've amended it to make it even clearer.

Comment: Ok try it. The only thing I wanted to say is that I'd *avoid* switching the editor and using bpy.ops* isn't a bad thing @Lewis

Comment: Tried a lot and I think changing the area could be ok in your case but you need to test it extensively... @Lewis