# How do I get a cylinder arrangement of arrays with gradient (increasing/decreasing) heights?

Tags: modeling

I have the following arrangement of same height cylinders in constanct distances and with constant diameter.
[image]Anyone knowing whether I can make cylinders with increasing height as we reach the center of the arrangement. Something like a 3D Gaussian bell whith cylinders instead of points.

The code I am using to create them is the following:

```
import bpy, random
from math import radians
from mathutils import Vector

row = 10
column = 10

for i in range(row):
    for j in range(column):
        l = Vector()
        r = Vector()
        d = Vector()
        l.x = i*7
        l.y = j*7
        l.z = 1.5 
        d = 3
        for xyz in r:
            r.xyz = radians(0)
        bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cylinder_add(vertices=36,
                                            radius=1,
                                            depth=d,
                                            location=l,
                                            rotation=r,
                                            )
```

Thanks!

Comment: @RayMairlot thank you for your reply. I adjusted the question according to your remarks.

Answer (score 4):

You have several flaws in your design.

- The normal distribution is usually a two-dimensional function which only takes one variable as an input. You could multiply f(x) and f(y) and use the resulting value as the height.
- Nearing a lot of iterations, you [shouldn't use `bpy.ops`](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/2848/30849)
  Use the `bmesh` module to edit meshes and link the data blocks manually to the scene.
- `Vector` objects can be instantiated with a tuple
- Blender is slow with a lot of objects, aim to include all geometry in one object in the future

[image: normal distributed cylinder]

The resulting code may seem convoluted, but is faster and easier to maintain.

```
import bpy
import bmesh
import math
from mathutils import Vector

RADIUS = 0.16
HEIGHT = 32
SEGMENTS = 32
DISTANCE = 1
COLS = 20
ROWS = 20
SCALE = 1

MEAN = 0
STD_DEVIATION = 4

def normal_dist(x):
    global MEAN, STD_DEVIATION
    mean = MEAN
    std_deviation = STD_DEVIATION

    exponent = - math.pow(x - mean, 2) / (2 * math.pow(std_deviation, 2))
    return 1 / (std_deviation * math.pow(2*math.pi, 0.5)) * math.exp(exponent)

bm = bmesh.new()
bmesh.ops.create_circle(bm, segments=SEGMENTS, diameter=RADIUS*2, cap_ends=True)
bm.faces.ensure_lookup_table()
ret = bmesh.ops.extrude_discrete_faces(bm, faces=bm.faces)
bmesh.ops.translate(bm, vec=Vector((0,0, HEIGHT)), verts=ret['faces'][0].verts)


scn = bpy.context.scene

name = "me"

for i in range(COLS):
    for j in range(ROWS):
        pos = Vector((i - COLS/2, j - COLS/2, 0))
        pos *= DISTANCE

        name = "cylinder_" + str(i) + "_" + str(j)
        if name not in bpy.data.meshes:
            me = bpy.data.meshes.new(name)
        else:
            me = bpy.data.meshes[name]
        bm.to_mesh(me)

        if name not in bpy.data.objects:
            ob = bpy.data.objects.new(name, me)
        else:
            ob = bpy.data.objects[name]
            ob.data = me

        ob.location = pos.copy()
        pos *= SCALE
        ob.scale.z = normal_dist(pos.x) * normal_dist(pos.y) * HEIGHT

        if ob.name not in scn.objects:
            scn.objects.link(ob)


bm.free()
```

[image: wow]
<sup>*Sooo cool.*</sup>