# How calculate the surface curvature for each vertex of a mesh?

Tags: mesh, scripting, vertices

I want to calculate the curvature value for each vertex of my mesh. All the scripts suggested here [Is there a way to calculate mean curvature of a triangular mesh?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/146819/is-there-a-way-to-calculate-mean-curvature-of-a-triangular-mesh) don't work for me.
These are the script (written by *lemon*) and the mesh mentioned above after running the script.

```
import bpy
import bmesh
from mathutils import Vector
from math import sqrt, asin

# Helper function to select vertices
def select_vertices( obj, indices, end_with_mode ):
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'OBJECT')
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'EDIT') 
    bpy.ops.mesh.select_mode(type="VERT")
    bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action = 'DESELECT')
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'OBJECT')
    for index in indices:
        obj.data.vertices[index].select = True
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = end_with_mode) 

def ensure_vertex_group( obj, group_name ):
    vertex_group = obj.vertex_groups.get( group_name )
    if not vertex_group:
        vertex_group = obj.vertex_groups.new( name = group_name )
    for i in range( len(obj.data.vertices) ):
        vertex_group.add( [i], 0, 'ADD' )
    return vertex_group

def assign_to_vertex_group( obj, group_name, curvatures ):
    vertex_group = ensure_vertex_group( obj, group_name )

    curvatures = [abs(c) for c in curvatures]

    min_curvature = min( curvatures )
    max_curvature = max( curvatures )
    vg_fac = 1.0 / (max_curvature - min_curvature) if max_curvature != min_curvature else 1.0

    for i, vert in enumerate( obj.data.vertices ):
        vertex_group.add( [vert.index], (curvatures[i] - min_curvature) * vg_fac, 'REPLACE' )

def index_of( element, sequence ):
    for i, e in enumerate( sequence ):
        if e == element: return i
    return -1

def search_link( value, links, position ):
    for l in links:
        if l[position] == value: return l
    return None

def rotate( l, n ):
    return l[n:] + l[:n]

# Get vertices in the face order but starting from a given vert
def following_verts_of_vert( vert, face ):
    i0 = index_of( vert, face.verts )
    i1 = (i0 + 1) % 3
    i2 = (i0 + 2) % 3
    return face.verts[i0], face.verts[i1], face.verts[i2]

# Create the oriented ring around vert
def ring_from_vert( vert ):
    vertices = []
    for face in vert.link_faces:
        i0, i1, i2 = following_verts_of_vert( vert, face )
        vertices.append( [i1, i2] )
    result = vertices[0]    
    added = True
    while added and len(vertices):
        added = False
        prev = search_link( result[0], vertices, 1 )
        if prev:
            result = [prev[0]] + result
            vertices.remove( prev )
            added = True
        next = search_link( result[-1], vertices, 0 )
        if next and next[1] not in result:
            result.append( next[1] )
            vertices.remove( next )
            added = True
    return result

def curvature_along_edge( vert, other ):
    normal_diff = other.normal - vert.normal
    vert_diff = other.co - vert.co
    return normal_diff.dot( vert_diff ) / vert_diff.length_squared

def angle_between_edges( vert, other1, other2 ):
    edge1 = other1.co - vert.co
    edge2 = other2.co - vert.co
    product = edge1.cross( edge2 )
    sinus = product.length / (edge1.length * edge2.length)
    return asin( min(1.0, sinus) )

def mean_curvature_vert( vert ):
    ring = ring_from_vert( vert )
    ring_curvatures = [curvature_along_edge( vert, other ) for other in ring]
    total_angle = 0.0
    curvature = 0.0
    for i in range(len(ring)-1):
        angle = angle_between_edges( vert, ring[i], ring[i+1] )
        total_angle += angle
        curvature += angle * (ring_curvatures[i] + ring_curvatures[i+1])
    
    return curvature / (2.0 * total_angle)

def mean_curvature( obj, threshold ):

    # Get bmesh access on the mesh
    bm = bmesh.new()
    bm.from_mesh( obj.data )

    bm.verts.ensure_lookup_table()
    bm.edges.ensure_lookup_table()
    bm.faces.ensure_lookup_table()

    above_threshold = {}
    curvatures = []
    for vert in bm.verts:
        curvature = mean_curvature_vert( vert )
        curvatures.append( curvature )
        if abs(curvature) > threshold:
            above_threshold[vert.index] = True
    
    return curvatures, above_threshold

print( '-------------' )

bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'OBJECT')

obj = bpy.context.active_object

threshold = 0.01
curvatures, above_threshold = mean_curvature( obj, threshold )

assign_to_vertex_group( obj, 'Curvatures', curvatures )

select_vertices( obj, above_threshold, 'OBJECT' )
```

[image: cat]

Comment: a bit old question/answer... but how is the mesh of the cat? If very detailed the local curvature will be very low.

Comment: ok... gave it a look. Probably your mesh is smooth and shows few curvature. Try to accentuate it in line 33. Replace the factor by a higher value: `    vg_fac = 4.0 / (max_curvature - min_curvature) if max_curvature != min_curvature else 1.0`

Comment: Retested it with highpoly and looks coherent: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IXZ54.jpg

Comment: @lemon Thank You for your answer! The mesh is detailed: It has about 28000 vertices! (sorry, I am new with Python and Blender).

Comment: Hello Davide. Could you upload the mesh so that I can give a look?

Comment: You can use http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ and paste the result link here. If blend file...

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=q6bLaaVZ" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/q6bLaaVZ/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [script here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/147371/19156) is correct but you have few high value so this is not really visible, or they are in hidden parts.

I've added a `magnify` factor to compensate if wanted:

[image]

Updated file:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Great answers.. I'm interested in finding the _directions_ of principal curvature, for non-animated NPR.. the closest I'm getting to an approach is [libigl](https://libigl.github.io/libigl-python-bindings/) .. any suggestions that would be prevent me from being buried, never to be seen again, would be welcome, if you happen to have looked into this yourself.

Comment: @RobinBetts, posted a question about it for you in chat/RenderFarm.