# Inconsistent/ Random behavior in Blender

Tags: mesh

I am generating some shape using python in Blender. Most of the times, when I run the code I get what I expect. But sometimes I see the broken mesh as I have shown in the figure.

As far as code's functionality is concerned, I am not using any random function/ number. Code is expected to give out deterministic result every time I run it.

Any suggestions on what might be causing this inconsistent behavior?

[image: Broken Mesh]

[image: Expected Mesh]

Comment: Possibly something in your code that triggers undefined behavior? https://docs.blender.org/api/current/info_gotcha.html#help-my-script-crashes-blender

Comment: Are you using any `bpy.ops` commands? Some are context sensitive, require certain windows or react to e.g. the mouse position.#

Comment: @RobertGützkow -- yes I think bpy.ops is the cause.

Comment: @Leander I am using bpy.ops. I think that might be the cause for the inconsistency. I have found this [post](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2848/why-avoid-bpy-ops)  and I will correct this and get back.