# Rotating objects different when using Python

Tags: python, tools

[image]For some reason when rotating a group of objects with a python script (transform_rotate) I get a different outcome than rotating the same group using the rotation tool

Before attempting to rotate I perform a cursor to origin set:

```
bpy.ops.object.origin_set(type=‘CURSOR_ORIGIN’, center=‘MEDIAN’)
```

No matter what I try the rotation performed with Python does not rotate around the object Cursor (now at the origin) but round a mysterious point. I have added print screens showing the differences as well as the code I use.
Even if I copy the code output printed after the manual rotation with the rotation tool and run that exact line I get a different rotation

I am performing a single 90 degree rotation around the Z axis

Code:

```
bpy.ops.object.origin_set(type=‘CURSOR_ORIGIN’, center=‘MEDIAN’)
bpy.ops.transform.rotate(value=-1.5708, orient_axis=‘Z’, orient_type=‘GLOBAL’,
orient_matrix=((1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0), (0, 0, 1)), orient_matrix_type=‘GLOBAL’,
constraint_axis=(False, False, True), mirror=True, use_proportional_edit=False,
proportional_edit_falloff=‘SMOOTH’, proportional_size=1.5,
use_proportional_connected=False, use_proportional_projected=False,
release_confirm=True)
```

Blender Version: 2.93
Python Version: 3.8.8

Comment: Operators in `bpy.ops` are [for interactive use through the UI and should be avoided in scripts](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2848/why-avoid-bpy-ops/2850#2850) because they depend on context. Using them through scripts may yield unexpected results at best, or fail entirely at worst. Manipulate data directly from `bpy.data` instead.

Comment: Thanks to duarte-farrajota-ramos comment. I rotated the objects after parenting them to an empty that was located at the origin