# loading blender files within a script

Tags: scripting

Is it generally bad practice to load a blender file within a script? I'm running into lots of trouble when doing so. For example here I want to create fresh file, then import a fbx and then save it:

```
def create_empty_scene():
    bpy.ops.wm.open_mainfile(filepath=r"D:\empty.blend")

def import_fbx_and_save_as_blend(fbx_filepath):
    create_empty_scene()
    bpy.ops.import_scene.fbx(filepath=fbx_filepath, )
```

This gives me an error wihin the fbx import:

```
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 3.1\3.1\scripts\addons\io_scene_fbx\import_fbx.py", line 2849, in _
    root_helper.build_hierarchy(fbx_tmpl, settings, scene, view_layer)
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 3.1\3.1\scripts\addons\io_scene_fbx\import_fbx.py", line 2284, in build_hierarchy
    child.build_hierarchy(fbx_tmpl, settings, scene, view_layer)
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 3.1\3.1\scripts\addons\io_scene_fbx\import_fbx.py", line 2244, in build_hierarchy
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 3.1\3.1\scripts\modules\bpy\ops.py", line 132, in __call__
    ret = _op_call(self.idname_py(), None, kw)
RuntimeError: Operator bpy.ops.object.mode_set.poll() Context missing active object
```

Something even simpler does also not work:

```
 bpy.ops.wm.open_mainfile(filepath=r"D:\cube.blend")
 cube = bpy.context.scene.objects["Cube"]
 cube.select_set(True)
 print(bpy.context.selected_objects)
```

This results in an error regarding the context:
`AttributeError: 'Context' object has no attribute 'selected_objects'`

all these scripts work completely fine when no scene is loaded before.
I have the same happening when running this code via an operator or not.

In pipeline scripts I'm used to just load a file or refresh a scene etc. Is this a no-go in Blender or am I maybe missing something? I have noticed that appending files is working.

I'm fairly new to Blender scripting so excuse this trivial question.

Comment: Operators in `bpy.ops` are [for interactive use through the UI and should be avoided in scripts](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2848/why-avoid-bpy-ops/2850#2850) because they depend on context. Using them through scripts may yield unexpected results at best, or fail entirely at worst. Manipulate data directly from `bpy.data` instead.

Comment: mh, so how would I import a fbx in some batch process? Is that a problem with the fbx importer in this case?

Comment: I suggest adding a little timer right after loading the new file (0.1 second should do it but it depends on your rig), the context takes a bit of time to get initialized correctly. https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.app.timers.html

Comment: thanks for the suggestion @Gorgious! That would mean running eveything in a thread though I suppose.. I really wish blender would simply not return from loading if the program is not ready, that would alleviate the need.

Comment: I tried to package this functionality using threads but this is sadly crashing blender 
https://gist.github.com/sschoellhammer/b355b3313542eed69620d0549cd40fb0
I guess calling any ops like loading in a thread is a no go as well?

Comment: What you're trying won't work because `open_mainfile` results in a fresh start, so your call to `import_scene.fbx` will never be invoked.

Comment: @MartyFouts mh well it seems to be invoked, hence the error.. but how does it usually work when you need to load a file then? What's best practice there?

Comment: The usual case is to treat files like libraries and use the library interface to read from them, pulling out individual objects, or materials, or whatever.

Comment: thank you @MartyFouts, appending worked without problems indeed. I guess the missing piece of the puzzle for me now would be how to wipe a scene completely clean again. 
(just to make it work today, I turned to running blender headless and restarting for each file, not really ideal but at least I got something to batch)