# What [bpy.context] is needed to use/apply bpy.ops.geometry.attribute_convert?

Tags: python, uv, geometry-nodes, operator

I want to write a script that combines all geometry in one collection into a single (separate) object. With all modifiers applied.
I got most of it working but since I’m using geometry nodes to set UV coordinates in some of them, I need to convert the UVMap attribute beforehand for the joining to work properly.

Now the problem is everytime I call

```py
bpy.ops.geometry.attribute_convert(mode='UV_MAP')
```

It says invalid context (or something like that)

I tried overriding object, active_object, selected_object and selected_editable_objects
with the object(s) I that had the operator applied

First I thought it was because I was using evaluated meshes (which seem to play by their own rules, but even mesh_from_object (or whatever it’s called) didn’t help it

Comment: Operators in `bpy.ops` are [for interactive use through the UI and should be avoided in scripts](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2848/why-avoid-bpy-ops/2850#2850) because they depend on context. Using them through scripts may yield unexpected results at best, or fail entirely at worst. Manipulate data directly from `bpy.data` instead.

Comment: Yeah figured, I just hoped there would be a way around it cause iterating over thousands of vertices/face loops and copying data may not be the most efficient way

Comment: Just because you are manipulating the data directly doesn't mean you have to iterate over every vertex. You're just doing things like `new_obj = obj.copy()` rather than `bpy.ops.object.duplicate()`.