# How to bake rigidbody physics to keyframes using python scripts when running from terminal?

Tags: python, animation, physics, keyframes, rigid-body-simulation

In GUI, it's easy this operation in Object -> Rigid Body -> Bake to keyframes. How to do that in python scripts?

I tried to write some code as below:

```
bpy.ops.anim.keyframe_insert(type='BUILTIN_KSI_LocRot')
bpy.ops.rigidbody.objects_remove()
bpy.ops.rigidbody.bake_to_keyframes(frame_start=1, frame_end=25)
```

And I got:

```
RuntimeError: Operator bpy.ops.anim.keyframe_insert_by_name.poll() failed, context is incorrect
```

Any solutions?

Comment: Operators in `bpy.ops` are [for interactive use through the UI and should be avoided in scripts](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2848/why-avoid-bpy-ops/2850#2850) because they depend on context. Using them through scripts may yield unexpected results at best, or fail entirely at worst. Manipulate data directly from `bpy.data` instead.