# How do I scale a specific set of vertices via the api

Tags: python, mesh, scripting, vertices, transforms

I'm trying to programatically apply a partial scaling to a mesh. For this specific scaling, I'm trying to replicate what happens when you've selected a number of vertices of a mesh in Edit Mode and scale them by pressing 'S' to bring them closer together or farther apart.

Like so:
[image: [img]]

What I've tried is this:

```
bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')

# object was originally a plane which I extruded into the z-axis, so this selects the upper half of the mesh.
upper_verts = [vert for vert in glyph_obj.data.vertices if vert.co[2] > 0]
        
for vert in upper_verts:
    vert.select = True
    
bpy.ops.transform.resize(value=(0.9, 0.9, 0.9), orient_type='GLOBAL', orient_matrix=((1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0), (0, 0, 1)), orient_matrix_type='GLOBAL', mirror=True, use_proportional_edit=False, proportional_edit_falloff='SMOOTH', proportional_size=1, use_proportional_connected=False, use_proportional_projected=False, snap=False, snap_elements={'INCREMENT'}, use_snap_project=False, snap_target='CLOSEST', use_snap_self=True, use_snap_edit=True, use_snap_nonedit=True, use_snap_selectable=False)
```

Where  `glyph_obj` is a bpy `Object` .

The last command, the `bpy.ops.transform.resize`, I copied from the info window from when I performed the operation by hand.

I can see in the viewer that my script *does* select all the appropriate vertices, but no transformation is performed. No errors are generated either. Because I followed programmatically all the steps I would have done by hand (I think), I don't know what I'm missing.

Comment: Operators in `bpy.ops` are [for interactive use through the UI and should be avoided in scripts](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2848/why-avoid-bpy-ops/2850#2850) because they depend on context. Using them through scripts may yield unexpected results at best, or fail entirely at worst. Manipulate data directly from `bpy.data` instead.

Comment: I would try going out of edit mode then in again, it should force the selection state to be updated

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos Yeah I sort of knew that, but had to use bpy.ops operators for some imports and then continued using them. Think I'll stick to bmesh from now on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without an operator:

```py
import bmesh
from bpy import context as C
from mathutils import Vector

condition = lambda v: v.co.z > 0
scale = 0.9

ob = C.object
me = ob.data
bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(me)
verts = [v for v in bm.verts if condition(v)]
average = sum((v.co for v in verts), start=Vector()) / len(verts)

for v in verts:
    offset = v.co - average
#    direction = offset.normalized()
#    v.co += direction * scale
    v.co += offset * (scale - 1)
    
bmesh.update_edit_mesh(me)
```