# Store location of selected objects then restore them with python script

Tags: python

I'm modifying the Template -> Python -> Batch Export script to batch export a bunch of .glb files

During export I need to zero out the location of the object using -

```
bpy.ops.object.location_clear(clear_delta=False)
```

But, I want store the objects location before I zero them with this function - then restore it's location after the location is zero'd and exported. This is because I need the transforms zero'd out when I import them into another program.

I am new to python in blender, so I started by trying to print the location of the selected object with -

```
print(bpy.ops.object.location)
```

But even with this simple print statement, I'm stuck, as I can't get the script to print the actual x,y,z coordinates.

Can anybody help me out with the code for this? Thanks a bunch

Comment: Operators in `bpy.ops` are [for interactive use through the UI and should be avoided in scripts](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2848/why-avoid-bpy-ops/2850#2850) because they depend on context. Using them through scripts may yield unexpected results at best, or fail entirely at worst. Manipulate data directly from `bpy.data` instead.

Comment: object location can be accessed or changed with `bpy.data.objects["your_object_name"].location`. If you have a parent-child relationship this might be a little more complicated since you need to access the world matrix of your object instead.